# PostGIS - How to calculate linestring length from WGS84 after transforming from OSGB 36

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, wgs84

I am having problems getting lengths from multilinestrings after transforming data from EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid to EPSG:4326/ WGS 84.

I'm doing this conversion to import a roads shapefile into a PostGIS database that uses WGS84 as default. However, when I try to calulate lengths, I'm having weird readings.

Firstly I thought about some incorrect transformation, but after doing some additional tests in an empty database importing the layer without transforming it (OSGB 1936 reference), I´m still puzzled:

The following query returns contradictory results

```
SELECT  
    ST_Length(geom) AS length_OSGB
    ,ST_Length_Spheroid(ST_Transform(geom,4326),'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]') As length_WGS84    
FROM osgb36_data
WHERE id = 108
```

this yields 338 meters for the OSGB36 length and 482 meters for the WGS84 length. The right one is 338 meters.

I've done the importation to the database using QGIS and DBmanager.

Also, I had to guess the initial projectios, as the .prj was missing, but projecting the result over google maps results in a perfect match.

Any hint is welcome

**EDIT:**

This is the WKT for the element in the example, as suggested:

```
    SRID=27700;MULTILINESTRING((
 423216.279 574665.249 0,
 423206.315 574708.077 44.649,
 423158.458 574896.911 242.525,
 423132.406 574993.061 344))
```

Well, that's weird, seems like they were using the z coordinate to register the accumulated distance for each point in the linestring... That could explain the issue with the wrong distances

Comment: Paste the WKT of the object itself (ST_AsEWKT(geom)) so others can verify.

Comment: How do you know that 338m is the right answer?

Comment: One of the fields of the feature is the total length of the segment. I'll post the wkt tomorrow . Thanks for the interest

Comment: ewkt posted...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The length functions work differently with 3D linestring geometries:

- [`ST_Length`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html) - returns 2D distances for `geometry` types, and oddly 3D distances for `geography` types (but not in this question)
- [`ST_Length_Spheroid`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length_Spheroid.html) - returns 3D distances for `geometry` types

Your example is in 3D, so it will calculate the 3D length with `ST_Length_Spheroid` and the 2D length with `ST_Length` on a `geometry`.

However, if you always want 2D lengths, you can force the geometry to a 2D linestring using either [`ST_Force2D` or `ST_Force_2D`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Force_2D.html) function (the name change in PostGIS 2.1).

```
SELECT ST_Length(geom) AS length_27700,
  ST_Length_Spheroid(ST_Transform(ST_Force2d(geom), 4326), spheroid) AS length_spheroid_2d,
  ST_Length_Spheroid(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), spheroid) AS length_spheroid_3d
FROM (
  SELECT 'SRID=27700;MULTILINESTRING((
      423216.279 574665.249 0,
      423206.315 574708.077 44.649,
      423158.458 574896.911 242.525,
      423132.406 574993.061 344))'::geometry AS geom,
    'SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]'::spheroid
) AS f;

  length_27700   | length_spheroid_2d | length_spheroid_3d
-----------------+--------------------+--------------------
 338.39264086563 |   338.515774984236 |   482.622196178051
```

Comment: so why is different ST_Length(geom) and ST_Length_Spheroid(ST_Transform(geom, 4326), spheroid)? Aren't both of them 3d coords?

Comment: ST_Length is documented to calculate a 2D distance for geometries. ST_Length_Spheroid is documented to behave differently.

Comment: Thanks. I would add that clarification in the answer, that would help a lot. I'm marking this as the answer, although both yours and @nickves are good answers

Answer (score 1):

Postgis is correct.

Your line is in 3d space, and in fact has a length of ~482m even in the  British National Grid.

338 meters is also correct but it corespondents in the projection of the 3d line in the 2d space.

```
 with a as ( select st_Geomfromewkt('SRID=27700;MULTILINESTRING((
  423216.279 574665.249 0,
  423206.315 574708.077 44.649,
  423158.458 574896.911 242.525,
  423132.406 574993.061 344))') geom) 
   select ST_Length(geom) "2D Length", ST_3DLength(geom) "3D_Length" from a;


     2d_length    |    3d_length
 -----------------+-----------------
  338.39264086563 | 482.54086040695 (1 row)
```

Manual Links:
[ST_Length](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Length.html)
[ST_3DLength](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DLength.html)

**Edit:**
Related:
http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/measurement.html